# How use caching to improve the performance of a classified website?

Tags: database, performance, caching, yii

I have built classified website using Yii php framework. Now it is getting a lot of traffic. So I want to using caching to optimize the performance of the website.

There are two controllers I want to optimize.

One is the thread list controller: (example) http://www.shichengbbs.com/category/view/id/15

The other one the the thread controller: (example) http://www.shichengbbs.com/info/view/id/67900

What I have done:

1. the thread list is cached for 3mins.(The other option is update the thread list only when new thread comes)
2. set the last-modified time HTTP header for the thread view. (expire time is not set, as some user complain that the page appears unchanged after editing)
3. Partial caching the categories navigation fragment.(It appears on the left side of every page)
4. Use htaccess to set expire header for img/html/css/js.
5. Considered database sql caching for the thread list, but not done. As I thought it is the same as 1.

What else can I do to improve the website performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have done the [Performance Tuning guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance) point 1 and 3. It's really helpful.

For number 2 you can use the [CHttpCacheFilter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpCacheFilter)

```
class CategoryController extends Controller {

   private $_categoryLastUpdate;
   public function filters(){
      return array(
         array(
           'CHttpCacheFilter + view',
           'cacheControl' => " max-age=604800, must-revalidate",
           'etagSeedExpression' => function() {
             return $this->getCategoryLastUpdate();
           }
           'lastModifiedExpression' => function() {
             return $this->getCategoryLastUpdate();
           }
         )
      )
   }

   public function actionView($id){
      $object = Category::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);
      $this->render('view', array('object' => $object));
   }

   public function getCategoryLastUpdate(){
      if (!isset($this->_categoryLastUpdate)){
         $obj = Category::model()->findByPk($_GET['id'], array('select' => 'lastUpdate'));
         $this->_categoryLastUpdate
      }
      return $this->_categoryLastUpdate;
   }

}
```

It basically will calculate the ETag and LastUpdate by the category. And to save the query, it will first only calculate the `lastUpdate` of the `Category` object.

And for number one, you can always use the [CCacheDependency](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCacheDependency). Just make a field in the thread list object, e.g. `lastUpdate`. And when a new thread submitted, just update the field and use it for the CCacheDependency.

Since I see you are using a very large pagination, I think you want to read about [Four Ways to Optimize Paginated Displays](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/24/four-ways-to-optimize-paginated-displays/) (if you use MySQL for your database and thread search/list).

Comment: +1 for this, and also a) switch to nginx, b) cache widgets (like #3) at Redis/memcached and pulling them dynamically within nginx (without firing any PHP)

Comment: I have a login section at the top right corner. If I set an expire header, that login/logout section will be inconsistant.

Comment: You can set expire for guest only, CMIIW. you can extend CHttpCacheFilter to return different random e-tag or even return no-cache message in the HTTP header when the user is logged in.
Or you can make the login/logout section to be called using AJAX.

Comment: Honestly, I forgot a little bit about that. Maybe you can try it, extend the CHttpCacheFilter to, let's say, HttpGuestCacheFilter. In the prefilter, you check if the user is guest or has logged in. In the later case, you set header to send no-cache directive, and in the first case just act like normal CHttpCacheFilter. Try browsing as guest and then log in. See what's different. :P

You can read more here. http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Cache Manager with Memcache or APC. For example, http://code.google.com/p/memcache-flag/ . When you edit the list, then you can invalidate the cache item or tag. I suppose it could also just be done with regular APC / Memcache functions if you design is simple (set a key and delete it when it is no longer valid).

Use this to store serialized (or automatically serialized) data instead of retrieving it from mysql.